# HighCharts open link in new tab

Tags: highcharts

My chart has a title that is an href, but I need it to open in a new tab.

I've turned on useHTML and have target: "_blank" but it's not working.

Comment: Check this configuration, from what I tested it should work fine:
https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/9ta4d1wj/

Comment: Thank you so much... I had it typed as target:"_blank" when it should have been done with an equal sign rather than the colons.